# Test flight locale does not return local locale for associated apple id

Tags: ios, testflight, storekit

We have an app implements subscription feature vi app store.  We show subscription fee on our app which value is taken from StoreKit.

When distributing as ad-hoc all despite the associated app store of apple id used to sign in the device, StoreKit always return Japanese locale(we develop our app in Japan)

When distributing as Test Flight then Store Kit locale returns US locale.

We don't know if they are some testing feature controlled by apple or we did something wrong.

Anyone know why this is happening and if it will return proper locale if deployed to app store.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, create a sandbox user in your Testflight management console and set the correct language/region for it. Then, on the testing device go to Settings -> App Store -> Sandbox User and sign in with that user.

Some time ago, only sandbox users could test in-app purchases. Nowadays, however, every user gets an automatically assigned sandbox user when testing an app through test flight. This auto-created user gets the locale US assigned to it.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101316